# Countif formula with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

In my workbook, I have a 4 spreadsheets - Data, Amy, Betty, Connie. Data has the following columns:

```
  Column A   Column B                  Column C             Column D
```

Row 3 Employee   Total tasks last 30 days.   Total tasks last 7 days.   Date/Time Last task Assigned
Row 4 Amy
Row 5 Betty
Row 6 Connie

In A1 - worker with oldest task Date/Time Assigned.  Cell B1 contains the answer to cell A1 by providing the employees name.

I enter the data in the individual workers spreadsheets (Amy, Betty, Connie) and my Data worksheet provides the summary.  On my data worksheet, I have formulas that count the number of tasks within the last 7 days and last 30 days by using the date/time assigned column (Column E)in the individual worksheets.  Currently, if someone is out of the office, on their individual worksheet, I enter OUT in the task column (Column B) and the date/time that they will return in the date/time assigned column (Column E)so it will skip them for B1 on my Data worksheet.   I need a formula that would not count the date/time assigned if they were OUT as a task, when calculating in columns B and C in the data worksheet.

Here is the formula that I have currently for Column B (total tasks last 30 days)

{=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&A4&"'!"&"E1:E1000"),">="&(NOW()-30))}

The formula that I have for cell B1 is:
{=INDEX(A4:A14,MATCH(MIN(E4:E14),E4:E14,0))}

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: there is the countifS formula that allows multiple ifs

Comment: How would I add it to my countif formula {=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&A4&"'!"&"E1:E1000"),">="&(NOW()-30))}

Comment: A1 is just text explaining what is in B1

Comment: This is referencing a sheet directly, but does only count if both conditions are met. `=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!E:E,">="&NOW()-30,Sheet2!B:B,"<>OUT")`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
=COUNTIFS(Amy!E2:E1000,">="&(NOW()-30),Amy!A2:A1000,"<>out")
```

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested in the comments, the `COUNTIFS` formula is what you want to use. Information about its usage can be found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx).

Adding the condition for excluding the "OUT" values would make the formula look like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(""&A4&"!"&"E1:E1000"),">="&(NOW()-30),INDIRECT(""&A4&"!"&"B1:B1000"),"<>OUT")
```